# Better Steam Store (Windows application or website)

Tags: steam

I have enough of official Valve Steam Store (client / web).
It lacks basic features to make browsing of their homungous inventory bearable.

Is there an alternative to Valve's Steam app for Windows (preferred) or at least alternative web site that does a better job?

Features I'm looking for:

- Hide all early access games (from all listings)
- Hide all unreleased games = preorders (from all listings)
- Hide all Greenlight games (from all listings)
- Blacklist for titles you don't want to see anywhere ever
- Blacklist for genres you don't want to see (have recommended etc.)
- Support for search with mixed words and tags and negative words and tags (like Google's: fruit -apple)

Shopping features like best price, price history etc. that "Enhanced Steam" browser addon has would be nice.

Also yes, I did google for this, but "Steam" is a very frequent word and it's hard to find anything for me.

I found:

- ["Enhanced Steam" browser addon](http://www.enhancedsteam.com/). That for some reason most of the time doesn't work for me. (Is Valve blocking it?) But mainly doesn't have the features I'm looking for.
- Couple of web portals like http://www.steamgifts.com/sales/recommended - Not very helpful.

Comment: I can't give you an answer because this website can't cover all of your needs. This website can only cover by highlighting your owned dan wishlisted game. You can also search the history of price and best deal the games. This website is SteamDB, https://steamdb.info

Comment: @Shokatsuryō Thanks for a tip. I guess the web does what Enhanced Steam addon should do. Sadly doesn't have any of the main features I'm looking for. Still a useful thing to have. Thanks